# Will a longitudinal wave propagate "forever" in a tube?

Tags: waves, water

I understand that the wave will lose energy due to "friction" between the, lets say, water molecules, but in my mind at least the biggest loss of energy in a wave is normally the dispersion of it. What I mean by this is if you drop a stone in a pond the wave ripples outwards and is spread out so it loses energy very quickly. But in a tube this doesn't happen. So my question is: if you send a pulse through a pipe, if we discount the "friction" between molecules, will the wave go on forever?

EDIT: When I say "propagates forever" I mean the wavefront continues to move at the same speed and direction and intensity (amplitude)

Practical example: If a toilet is plugged and I send a pulse through the pipe with a plunger, assuming the pipe was completely straight and we lost no energy to the "friction" between molecules, would the wavefront make it to the blockage with the same speed and intensity as it initially had?

Comment: If you "discount friction" than even water waves "go on forever".  The energy density just gets less and less.  Your question seems under-defined as to what you really mean by "propagate forever".

Comment: @BrandonEnright, I updated the question with more info

Comment: Note:  "dispersion" has a very specific meaning in the context of the physics of waves, and you're not using it correctly - you're looking for "dispersing", or "spreading out".

Comment: To "discount" friction is not enough, the tubes wall has to be inelastic too.